# Is there a general component/form for connecting to a database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, ado.net

I need a form where I could easly select a database source (from file or network) using ODBC or any other data provider, but I don't want to code it myself.

Are there any component or open source code that could save me the trouble?

Thanks in advance.

PS.: to be used with ADO.NET

Comment: Are you asking for a connection string or an application that generates connection strings on the fly?

Comment: Link: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;310083

Comment: Another: http://www.brothersoft.com/connection-string-builder-242193.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such component in the .NET framework itself, however Microsoft released the code for the Visual Studio connection dialog. The API is a bit awkward, but it works like a charm.

You can [download it here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection/)

Comment: For the life of me I cannot figure out why the API is so strange, but it worked fine for me as well.

Comment: I think the reason the API is so strange is because it was not originally designed as a stand-alone component, it was part of VS. When they took it out of VS they didn't bother to make the API more intuitive...